# How can I convert a google maps circle into GeoJSON?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I need to convert a google maps [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) into GeoJSON. [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) doesn't support circles so I want to generate an N-sided polygon. I found [a nice method for generating a regular N-sided polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198179/879121) but that requires the radius to be defined in the coordinate system while the radius of a circle in Google Maps is defined in meters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Google Maps has a handy set of [spherical functions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) in the geometry library that makes this really easy for us. Specifically, we want the `computeOffset` function:

> Returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north).

We have the origin (the center of the circle) and a distance (the radius of the circle), so we just need to calculate a set of headings for the points based on how many sides we want.

```
function generateGeoJSONCircle(center, radius, numSides){

  var points = [],
      degreeStep = 360 / numSides;

  for(var i = 0; i < numSides; i++){
    var gpos = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, radius, degreeStep * i);
    points.push([gpos.lng(), gpos.lat()]);
  };

  // Duplicate the last point to close the geojson ring
  points.push(points[0]);

  return {
    type: 'Polygon',
    coordinates: [ points ]
  };
}
```

The [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) is not included by default. You must specifically ask for it via the [libraries parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries).